# Liferay portlet ajax request not hitting the tomcat after some time

Tags: ajax, tomcat, datatable, liferay, spring-portlet-mvc

I have multiple portlets on my page. Both the portlets lists some data. After using the portal for some time, ajax requests from one portlet fails to get a response. Whereas the other portlet is working fine. When I looked into the logs, the ajax request is not even hitting tomcat.

What could be the issue?

Comment: check on client side with firebug or similar network request monitoring. They also show the ajax requests

Comment: I am observing the net tab in the firebug. The ajax call will always be waiting for the response.

Comment: can you check whether its generating correct URL or not